# Zend duplicated rows on mysql insert

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

For some reason, when I do an mysql db insert from Zend, my row is dulpicated. I've tried a direct insert via phpmyadmin and it works perfect, so its not a mysql server problem.

This is the code I use:

```
<?php

class Model_Team extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {

    protected $_name = 'team';

    public function createUser($data) {
        $user = $this->createRow();
        $user->name = $data['name'];
        $user->title = $data['title'];
        $id = $user->save();
        return $id;
    }
}

?>
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I've found that this duplication only occurs when i call the form via AJAX (modal box), although the form post is normal, not an ajax request)

Comment: Just to be sure: 1.- Did you look the network tab on "Firebug/Chrome Developer Tools" to check if the post is sent just once? 2.- Did you check that createUser method is called just once in your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why your code is double pumping the database on save but it should'nt matter as you're using the Row object and save(). (save() inserts or updates)
You may want to restructure your createUser() function so that it can't create a new row if the row already exists.

```
<?php

class Model_Team extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {

protected $_name = 'team';

public function createUser(array $data) {

    $user = $this->createRow();
    //test if user has id in the array
    if (array_key_exists('id', $data)){
        $user->id = $data['id'];
    }
    $user->name = $data['name'];
    $user->title = $data['title'];
    $user->save();
    //no need to create a new variable to return the user row
    return $user;
   }
}
```

This method will create and update a user row.

To help you further I'll need to see the controller code most of my double pumps have happened there.

Comment: Not possible all the time if there is an auto increment.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using createRow() have you tried using insert()?

```
/**
 * Insert array of data as new row into database
 * @param array $data associative array of column => value pairs.
 * @return int Primary Key of inserted row
 */
public function createUser($data)
{
    return $this->insert($data);
}
```

Also - could we see the ajax code? It may be that the form is being posted as well?

Comment: Using $this->insert() also duplicates the entry. I'm using facebox jquery plugin to deal with the modal box.